# Local Storage on Mobile Devices

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, local-storage

I'm working on an app at my job that is using localStorage. We will be migrating to server side.

It is a car app that remembers the user. With this app they can lock/unlock the car, start it, etc.

We are using sessionStorage and to keep the username/password in localStorage if the user checks "Remember Me".

There is nothing wrong with the app, but some users are saying they are checking "Remember Me" but sometimes they have to re-login all over again.

The question I have is if localStorage could be deleted automatically for an application on both Android and Apple?

I read that prior to iPhone 6, localStorage would be deleted if the phone had too much memory storage. I also read that here.

I know this isn't a coding issue, but any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you consider to be localStorage?

Comment: `"We are using sessionStorage and to keep the username/password in localStorage"` so are you using sessionStorage or localStorage? They are very different, as sessionStorage gets automatically deleted on window (or maybe tab idk) close, and localStorage should exist forever. The second problem with that sentence, why are you storing the password in local/sessionStorage? That's a big potential security risk.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I know the difference. I didn't set up the app and we are migrating it. My question was the instances where localStorage on a mobile device could be deleted.